# libgdx making my physics upside down?

Tags: java, libgdx, physics

For some reason when I use the same code in a previous physics test without libgdx it works fine. But with libgdx it thinks the ground is in the sky.

```
package com.me.randomtests;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import...

public class Randomtest implements ApplicationListener {
ShapeRenderer SR;
int x = 100, y = 100, radius = 10;
double deltax = 0, deltay = 0, gravity = 15, energyloss = .65, dt = .2;


@Override
public void create() {      
    SR=new ShapeRenderer();
}


@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void render() {  
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  SR.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
    SR.filledCircle(x, y, radius);
    SR.setColor(Color.BLUE);    
    SR.end();

    Update();

}

public void Update(){
    System.out.println(y);
    if(x + deltax > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - radius -1 ){
        x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - radius - 1;
        deltax = - deltax;
    }else if(x + deltax < 0 + radius){
        x = 0+radius;
        deltax= - deltax;
    }else{
        x += deltax;
    }

    if(y>Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - radius - 1){
        y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - radius - 1;
        deltay *=.9;
        deltay = -deltay;
    }else{
        //vel formuka
        deltay += gravity *dt; 
        //pos formula
        y +=deltay*dt + .5*gravity*dt*dt;
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

what is my problem here? Also does anyone know why 0 is at the bottom with libgdx?

Comment: LibGDX is y-up by defaut. Try `gravity = -15` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Noone! Haven't tried it yet since I'm on mobile but I'm pretty sure that should work.